# %s format specifier in printf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[11] = "HelloWorld";
    printf("%s\n",str);
    printf("%s\n",str+3);

    /* This Line here is the devil */
    printf("%s\n",str[2]); // %s needs an addr not a value.

    return 0;
}
```

Why does that line give a segmentation fault. Is it because `%s` in `printf` needs an address and not a value.
What is the actual reason ??

Comment: You gave it a letter instead of an address. So it tries to access the address "0x6c" (hex of "l") which is almost certainly an invalid address.

Comment: so accessing that memory location might turn out to be illegal and hence the segmentation fault.. OK..

Comment: @Bhargav: Mis-match in format specifier and actual type passed to `printf` results in an **Undefined Behavior**, and that is what your example does.

Comment: If there was a suspected reason, you could have tried removing it and see for yourself. +1 to the answer for good explanation though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str[2]` returns a char, not a pointer to a char.  So, `printf` will try to start reading at address `0x6c`.  Right there, there is a good chance that `0x6c` is an invalid address that will cause a segfault.  However, if it isn't invalid then `printf` will keep reading until it reaches a `0x00` character, which very well could enter into an invalid address range.

If you want to know precisely why it segfaults, you would need to follow along in a debugger, which might be interesting and educational.

If you wanted to fix the crashing line, you could change it to:

```
  printf("%s\n", &str[2]);
```

which I would consider to be better style than `str+2`.

Comment: That last suggestion I've already known.. I knew this is wrong but just couldn't figure out the precise reason for the segphault :)

Comment: The second sentence describes one possible behavior of one possible implementation, but there's no fundamental reason it's true. The correct answer is simply that OP broke the interface contract (`%s` requires a pointer to `char` in the corresponding argument position) and thus the behavior is undefined.